# How to track users across pages without using a cookie and without writing backend code?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I need to track users across pages without using a cookie. I do not have access to the web server, so my solution has to run from some JS each page can load.

Currently I am using a horrible solution of IP + timestamp.

So his navigation might look like this:

- 13:21:11 /index.php
- 13:21:15 /shop.php
- 13:21:35 /blue-shirt-1.php

Currently to track his session I have some logic like unique IP + navigated around in the past 10 minutes.

This is fine if every user visits the site once, and only for 10 minutes, or visits very infrequently, also for 10 minutes. But I need to be able to understand these two scenarios:

- If he sits at /blue-shirt-1.php for half an hour, and then clicks another link, that should be considered a part of the same session.
- If he closes his browser or navigates to a different website, and then comes back 5 minutes later, that should be considered a different session.

Is there any way to do this?

Note I can't use cookies because of a GDPR compliance issue.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use the onbeforeunload Event to track if the user is leaving your website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Yes I currently do that to track when they leave the current page they're on, but if they go to another page on the same website, how can I reliably tell it's from the same session? I guess I could do something like check the referer + very short time period between onbeforeunload and the new page loading. Thanks for the ideas, I'll ponder this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to cookie-based sessions could be an URL-based session.

You could generate your own sessionids and use them as parameters like `index.php?id=XXX` and if ther is no id given you could generate a new one.

You should also take a look at PHPs URL based session management: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

> Note that in this case the user could fake a new sessionid or use the id of an other user. For this
>   you could track the ids with the users ip and hold them after leaving
>   one page for a moment (for example by using onbeforeunload) and if the
>   given sessionid does not exist you could generate a new one, too...